# How to access VBA library via win32ole in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, vba, win32ole

I am trying to access the VBA method 'RGB' via Ruby:

[image: vba ole explorer]

The problem is this method belongs to the 'VBA' library not the 'Excel' library.  To connect to the Excel library I would do something like this:

```
require 'win32ole'
xl  = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')    # => opens Excel
xl.visible = true                          # => show it
@wb  = xl.Workbooks.open(excel_file)       # => adds a workbook
@ws = @wb.Worksheets(sheet)                # => open specific sheet
```

But I do not know how to connect to the VBA library.  I've tried:

```
require 'win32ole'
vba  = WIN32OLE.new('VBA.Application')
vba  = WIN32OLE.new('VBA')
```

Even better would be if I could somehow programmatically generate a list of all OLE libraries on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the `WIN320LE` thing, but if I were you, I'd create a vba script, and run that script from the shell via ruby, then pipe the output from that script into ruby as a string.

Not sure if this helps, just a generic pattern

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... the whole point of OLE libraries would be